# Quartz.Net - Every 3 weeks on Mon,Tue,Wed

Tags: c#, scheduling, quartz.net

I'm stuck with Quartz.NET cron trigger. 
I was able to imlpement all my scenarios apart the one below.

- **Every X weeks on Mon,Tue,Wed...**

I managed to do this

`0 31 15 ? * MON#2 *`

which triggers every second Monday.

Would it work with `0 31 15 ? * MON#2,TUE#2,WED#2 *` ??

I tried testing it on http://www.cronmaker.com however It only showed me Mondays as coming up dates.
My only requirement is to keep it simple - ie. no more than one trigger.

Comment: +1 for http://www.cronmaker.com!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quartz.NET, Recur Every x Weeks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866100/quartz-net-recur-every-x-weeks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with Brabster.
I don't think it is possible with a Cron Expression.

Quartz.net 2.0 has a new type of trigger called **CalendarIntervalTrigger** which can be used to manage different interval units.
You can read more [here](http://jvilalta.blogspot.com/2011/01/new-in-quartznet-20the-calendar.html).

**UPDATE**:

Here's the link to the quartz.net 2.0 [repository](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/2.x).

Comment: I keep hearing about Quartz.net 2.0 but i was unable to find any source code some more info about it. I heard some bad things about it as well (being unstable etc).

Comment: @Luke: I've updated my answer.You can find the link to quartz.net on GitHub. I probably mentioned it being unstable a couple of times here on SO. I know Marko Lahma - the guy behind it - has worked a lot on that project recently and fixed all the issues I had.

Comment: I have decided to give v2 a go. So i'm currently checking if it fits all my criteria. However, I do NOT see how I can use CalendarItervalTrigger to trigger every 3 weeks on tue, wed, fri for example.

Comment: Code repository is gone so this is just misleading

Answer (score 4):

I've used the Java Quartz implementation, assuming they are similar then I don't think it's possible to express what you need as a single CronTrigger.

In Java we have the [DateIntervalTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.0/org/quartz/DateIntervalTrigger.html), but I don't think this could do what you need in a single trigger either. Unfortunately, as triggers can't be composed in the API itself,I guess  there will be limits as to the complexity of triggers that can be expressed as a single trigger.

Comment: in fact it's from the same team

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would to have a trigger that fired every week attached to a job that figures out if X number of weeks has passed and starts the main job.

This might go against your 'keep it simple' requirement but it would be functional. I've had to implement something similar to ensure specific Job instances are triggered rather than a brand new instance.

You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866100/quartz-net-recur-every-x-weeks) as its asking pretty much the same thing.