# Quartz.NET Cron Expression for recurring after particular weeks

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net, cronexpression

What would be cron expression for following two cases:

[image: job scheduling]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is not possible with a sigle Cron expression.
Some people have asked similar questions recently. 
You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866100/quartz-net-recur-every-x-weeks) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740198/quartz-net-every-3-weeks-on-mon-tue-wed).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, the every 2 weeks part is not supported.