# Quartz scheduler cron expression for more than 1 week

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

How to schedule a task on sunday,wednesday,friday of every 2 or more weeks using cron expression in quartz schduler.My scheduling may start on any of the day.I know for 1 week we can use the following cron expression-
Cron format        0 0 12 ? * WED,FRI,SUN * 
Start time  Friday, November 16, 2012 7:34 AM

1. Friday, November 16, 2012 12:00 PM
2. Sunday, November 18, 2012 12:00 PM
3. Wednesday, November 21, 2012 12:00 PM
4. Friday, November 23, 2012 12:00 PM
5. Sunday, November 25, 2012 12:00 PM
   But,I cant figure out how to do it every 2 or more weeks.

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866100/quartz-net-recur-every-x-weeks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am afraid is not possible to do it just using a cron expression. Take a look to the doc about [How-To: Trigger That Executes Every 2 Weeks](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/BiWeeklyTrigger).