# Generate schedule for Every (x) days

Tags: schedule, quartz.net

I'm using ScheduleWidget and need to generate a schedule every (x) day.  It could be any number.  I also need to option to include or exclude weekends.  Any tips on how to do this?

```
var dailyBuilder = new ScheduleBuilder();
var dailySchedule = dailyBuilder.HavingFrequency(FrequencyType.Daily).Create();
```

This will build every day without skipping days, but I'd like something that is `"Every 3 days"` for example.

Comment: Is this for Quartz.net? C# doesn't have a built-in class called `ScheduleBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

In Quartz.net 2.0, there is new triggertype called Calendar interval trigger.  It has the following interval units:

IntervalUnit

- Minute
- Hour
- Day
- Week
- Month
- Year

Else look at it here: 
[Quartz.NET, Recur Every x Weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866100/quartz-net-recur-every-x-weeks)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish you could have a look at Hangfire.
In hangfire you can also schedule recurring jobs based on a cron expression (like you could with quartz). With cron expressions you can create any type of interval.

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-jobs-in-console-app.html

Hangfire or any kind of jobs is also a good idea from architectural standpoint. This way you can nicely apply the separation of concerns principle.